# Script in .ASP to create new page on server

Tags: asp-classic

I want to make an ASP script that can create a new page on the webserver and tell it what content that will be in the new .asp file.

How can i do that? :)

Comment: Before you get too far along with that idea, do you realize what a massive security hole that could be? Can you explain why you would want to that? I bet SO can come up with a much safer approach to meet your project goals.

Comment: Hi John, I want to make an upload page, where you can browse for the file enter description etc. and then when you click submit I want it to make a new page for this exact document, like youtube when the user uploads - it creates a new page :)

Comment: That is not how the YouTube pages work.  They use the methodology shown below from @JohnFx.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not to create a new page for each request. Instead you want to pre-create an ASP page that dynamically ouputs the a file based on the input of the user.

In your example of uploading a file to display. What you probably want to do is store the uploaded file somewhere and then create another ASP page that reads in the uploaded file and displays it using `Response.binarywrite` or `response.write`. Don't create a new ASP page for each uploaded file.

So for the sake of example, you would create an ASP script called "DisplayUploadedFile.asp" the code inside it would read in the file (wherever you are storing it on the server (for example in a DB) and then write it back out. The users would hit the same page regardless of which uploaded file they wanted to see with a parameter telling the script which to display. For example `DisplayUploadedFile.asp?fileID=12`

**CAUTION:** It is extremely dangerous security-wise to let users upload content that is displayed to other users. Don't do this unless you understand at a very high level what steps are necessary to make this functionality secure. Based on your question, I think it might be prudent to get a more senior programmer to review your solution before you publish it.